# add modules and themes to my project

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to add modules and themes to my Magento 2 project.

It supposes that after adding modules and themes, the website will have a specific design but it doesn't. I can't even see categories or products

what are the causes

Comment: Are you using which theme?

Comment: @EvinceDevelopment Template monster with some edit

Answer (score 0):

After installing theme run below command in sequence.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Go to admin follow below path

**Admin > Content > Design > Configuration**

Edit first Global row. Select you installed theme to **Applied Theme** and save it.

Flush cache from admin.

Comment: I did so, but still there is lost elements in frontend

Comment: May be that you need to configure from theme configuration and may be there is import sample data in theme configuration please follow theme guide

Comment: I think running `setup:upgrade` first before deploying static content will solve the issue.

Comment: @magefms I did so

Comment: @YomnaMansour, have you set your theme to be the theme of your frontend main website store? from **design > configuration** ?

Comment: @magefms I set it, it appears but it miss some elements

Comment: that might be a css issue. make sure your theme doesn't need a patch to work